# Tricentis Tosca - How to open a file which is the first file in a folder, or the only file in a folder. Note - I dont know the file name

Tags: file, tosca

The System Under Test generates some pdf files and saves the files to a particular folder. The challenge is that the pdf file name is randomly generated and I don't know the name. I need to open the file from the folder which is the most recent one, but I can't seem to find a way to open the file.

- I know part of the file name so I tried using wildcard for part of the file name, but it doesn't work
- I removed all other files from the folder and kept only one file in the folder, and then used wildcard instead of the complete file name, but that doesn't work either

Is there a way that I can read names of files present in a folder? Or open a pdf file using wildcard character? Or open the first file in the folder?

Comment: it is not possible to open a file using a wildcard! Not only in Tosca but in general. You must use full exact name.

Answer (score 0):

You could try PowerShell scripting (please refer attached screenshots)
Use the 'TBox Start Program' module.
In the Path attribute, mention the complete path of your PowerShell exe file (Eg: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe)
In the Directory attribute, mention the folder path(Eg: C:\Users\tosca\Documents\testfolder)
Put -command in arguments with ActionMode 'Select'.
As Argument, input the PowerShell script with your wild carded file name to copy the file name (Eg:
(Get-ChildItem *filename* | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).Name | Clip)

[Copy latest file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp8Pg.png)

Then use 'TBox Clipboard' to store the dynamic file name using ActionMode 'Verify'

[Save latest file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G984a.png)

Then you can buffer the target file as folderpath\filename.