# Tosca - Buffer first filename in a directory

Tags: automation, tosca

Just wanted to know how to buffer the filename of the first file in a given directory in Tosca

Comment: What do you mean by "first file"? There is no such thing as first file in a directory actually.

Comment: hello. what i meant by "first file" is when opening a folder in Windows, the topmost file in that folder. I hope that clears up.

Comment: No, it does not. What you as the topmost file depends on your sort settings.

Comment: You could try tweaking the solution mentioned here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482508/tricentis-tosca-how-to-open-a-file-which-is-the-first-file-in-a-folder-or-the/72765898#72765898